# Element value must be a constant expression

Tags: java, events, minecraft

I was trying to make an event system for my Minecraft client. After finishing it I tried to run it and came across an error `element value must be a constant expression`. This error came from a file **EventTarget** whose code is:

```java
package me.debug.moon.event;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface EventTarget {

    byte value() default EventPriority.THIRD;
}
```

The line `byte value() default EventPriority.THIRD;` was the line giving me the error.
If it helps here is the code to my **EventPriority** file:

```java
package me.debug.moon.event;

public class EventPriority {
    public static final Byte FIRST = 0, SECOND = 1, THIRD = 2, FOURTH = 3, FIFTH = 4;

    public static final Byte VALUE_AARAY[] = new Byte[] {FIRST, SECOND, THIRD, FOURTH, FIFTH};
}
```

I looked around in StackOverflow and saw a few questions like this but most of them were due to the libraries they used and were for Android Studio.

Also, I am using Gradle 7.1 (according to the gradle-wrapper.properties file)

I wanted to know if anyone can help me with solving this error

Comment: Try using `byte` instead  of `Byte`.  I do not think the latter can be a constant  expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your EventPriority class you use **Byte** (uppercase B), which is an object.

You should use **byte** (lowercase b), which is a primitive.

From the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28

> A compile-time constant expression is an expression denoting a value
> of primitive type or a String